# Extracting blockchain state at a specific block number to interact with deployed contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, ethers.js, openethereum

I want to extract main net state at a specific block number using geth or parity. Then using the extracted state I want to interact with contracts deployed during that time using ethers js.

Can someone please point me to the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Can point you with Ganache.

Comment: @goodvibration Sure! That would be great!

Comment: Are you on Truffle 5.x?

Comment: @goodvibration Yep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using Truffle & Ganache.

In `truffle-config.js`, extend the configuration of your network to something like this:

```
networks: {
    myNetwork: {
        host: ...,
        port: ...,
        network_id: ...,
        gas: ...,
        gasPrice: ...,
        networkCheckTimeout: 9000000000, // or some other large value
        provider: ganache.provider({
            gasLimit: ...,
            gasPrice: ...,
            default_balance_ether: ...,
            fork: "url of an archive node",
            fork_block_number: desiredBlockNumber
        })
    }
}
```

Update: you also need `const ganache = require('ganache-core');` in this file.