# Connect Ganache to Ropsten

Tags: ropsten, ganache

I want to connect Ganache to Ropsten such that i can see Ropsten's ledger with Ganache. Is this possible? if yes, what settings do I need to do on Ganache?

Answer (score 3):

`Ganache` is a local blockchain that you run in your own computer, whereas `Ropsten` is a public blockchain. Therefore, both are **different** blockchains, meaning that you connect either to one or another.

You can use Metamask, for instance, and easily change to your local blockchain (Ganache) or a public testnet (Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan...).

To set up Ganache with Metamask, go to settings->networks->Add network, and there you can put the values from your Ganache configuration (URL, port, chainId).

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @goodvibration, you could actually fork Ropsten network, run it locally (so you would be the only node), and then connect Ganache to this network. This might help you:

[Run a local fork of Ropsten](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/want-to-run-a-local-fork-of-ropsten)

Comment: The statement "`meaning that you connect either to one or another`" is wrong. Ganache is an EVM, not a blockchain network. You can configure it to fork the Ropsten blockchain network, and then simulate your "stuff" on it.

Comment: Well, according to their website: "Ganache is a personal blockchain for rapid Ethereum and Corda distributed application development" (we could debate whether a blockchain network without nodes is really a blockchain). However, I agree that you could fork the Ropsten network, run it locally and connect Ganache to it.

Comment: Hence "`you connect either to one or another`" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated the answer to include your proposal.

Comment: NP. Note that the answer linked in your answer is a relatively old (though not necessarily obsolete). As of Truffle v5, you can (also) do it directly in the truffle configuration file, as shown [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90115/16043).